# How to make Eclipse tell me on which line an error occurred?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, exception, nullpointerexception

Coming from Python I'm now trying to create an Android app. In this, I sometimes get errors, like a NullPointerException for example. The problem is that unlike Python, Eclipse doesn't tell me a line number at which the error occurred. It just gives me something like this:

```
10-09 10:03:59.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3289): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.android/com.example.android.ui.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Is there a way that I can get Eclipse to tell me the line at which the NullPointerException occurred?

=== EDIT===
Ah, I now look more detailed over the full error (below) and in there I see this line: om.example.android.ui.MyActivity.onResume(MyActivity.java:208), which is indeed the line at which it occurred.

So let's put my question like this then. Can I display only the errors in the code I've written myself, and not in all the other mumbo-jumbo?

```
10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.android/com.example.android.ui.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)
10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502):     at com.example.android.ui.widget.AmountFragment.setAmount(AmountFragment.java:79)
10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502):     at com.example.android.ui.MyActivity.onResume(MyActivity.java:208)
10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5211)
10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502):     ... 12 more
```

Comment: Please post how you log the exception. And also, is this the whole stack trace?

Comment: you probably are catching the exception and not printing the stacktrace.

Comment: I'm not doing anything. I just see the error occur in LogCat when I try for example to Log something which is null.

Comment: Look at the log lines next to this one, they typically would contain the location where the exception was thrown.

Comment: see the error log carefully , it tells you which line causes the error , better print your stacktrace ,and also you can put a break point on the first line of your application and debug application line by line

Comment: Just double click on the log line that correspond to the first error line. Here double click the lines just below "caused by: ...."

Comment: @Yume117 - Awesome! I see that I need to look at those lines a bit more carefully. I'd never seen Caused By before.. :| Thanks!

Comment: Yes this is a good tip. You can also run your application in debug mode with a break point in step by step mode until you find the line. With this method you can see in real time your variable to see if anything is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in the line 79 in `AmountFragment.Java`. The sentence of that line is trying to do something with an instance that is null.

DDMS perspective provides you a lot of information that debug perspective doesn´t. In ddms perspective you can wath Threads and the memory used for each thread, memory per application, see application and emulator heap, the allocation tracker (here you can step the asynchronous task i.e), the logcat are much more fine that debug console. One of the most useful function  is the Method profiling, where you can follow step by step the actions performed by your app.

Maybe this video would be helpful for you to debug an Android app: [How To Debug Android Applications in Eclipse](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqHYbm9e05A)

Comment: Hmmmm, you're right, I need to know more about debugging as a whole. It seems to go a bit different (and is harder) than in Python.. :) Thanks for the link. I'll be watching that in a minute!

Answer (score 0):

this line tells you:

```
                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502):     at com.example.android.ui.widget.AmountFragment.setAmount(AmountFragment.java:79)
 10-09 10:08:49.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3502):     at com.example.android.ui.MyActivity.onResume(MyActivity.java:208)
```